# Why do I get the error Call to undefined function even with include_once?(php)

Tags: php

I can't seem to figure out why it won't pick up the function. As you can figure by the include_once I have, the .php file is in another directory but I reference it correctly. I don't know php well at all but I've tried

```
    this::theFuctionIWant();
    phpIWantToInclude::theFunctionIWant();
    this->theFunctionIWant();
    phpIWantToInclude->theFunctionIWant();
```

Here is a watered-down version of the code. If you want more of the real code please let me know.

```
    <?php
    namespace Scripto\Api\Representation;
    
    use DateTime;
    use Omeka\Api\Representation\AbstractEntityRepresentation;
    
    class phpIWantToInclude extends AbstractEntityRepresentation
    {
    
        stuff
          .
          .
          .
    
        public function theFunctionIWant()
        {
           stuff
             .
             .
             .
           return other stuff;
        }
    
    }
    ?>
```

```
    <?php
    namespace Scripto\Form;
    include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."filePath/phpIWantToInclude.php");
    use Laminas\Form\Form;
     
    class BeepBoop extends Form
    {
    
        public function init()
        {
          
            stuff
              .
              .
              .
    
            $var = theFunctionIWant();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Don't you need a `phpIWantToInclude` object as `theFunctionIWant` is a method of that class?

Comment: @Musa that's what I thought but then I get the error " Class 'path\phpIWantToInclude' not found"

is this the wrong way to do it

$obj = new phpIWantToInclude;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view you must check your namespace, the namespace must match in the diferent files regardless the include_once or require_once.

Comment: This might be the problem but can you have multiple namespaces? because I can't change the namespace on either of these files.

Comment: You can have multiple namespace yes.